# assign one function to 3 buttons directing to outside websites

Tags: javascript, button, window.location

I found similar answers but not exactly what I was looking for.
how can I handle 3 buttons with 1 function? how to integrate document property into the solution?

Here is the code:

```js
function gotoUrl() {
  window.location.assign("https://www.google.com/")
}

function gotoUrl1() {
  window.location.assign("https://www.yahoo.com/")
}

function gotoUrl2() {
  window.location.assign("https://www.youtube.com/")
}
```

```html
<button class="one" onclick="gotoUrl()"> Google </button>
<button class="two" onclick="gotoUrl1()"> yahoo </button>
<button class="three" onclick="gotoUrl2()"> Youtube </button>
```

Comment: Why not simply use links instead?

Comment: `onclick="gotoUrl('https://www.google.com')"` and then `function gotoUrl(url) { window.location.assign(url) }`. But a link would be simpler indeed...

Comment: @JeremyThille, simpler and better for user that will actually know where the link is redirecting to.

Comment: its part of homework I got and breaking my head 3 days now :-)

Comment: Does the homework also suggest using `onclick`? Whatever course you’re in teaches really bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter `params` into a function, which is a variable included in a function when it is run. Here is your modified code only using 1 function:

```
<!-- html -->
<button class="one" onclick="gotoUrl('https://www.google.com')"> Google </button>
<button class="two" onclick="gotoUrl('https://www.yahoo.com')"> yahoo </button>
<button class="three" onclick="gotoUrl('https://www.youtube.com')"> Youtube </button>
```

```
// javascript
function gotoUrl(link /*link is a param, now we can use it as a variable in our function*/){
     window.location.assign(link)
}
```

w3schools on params : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: thank you so much. can you explain please how the  "link" argument inside the function was referred to each button?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function gotoUrl() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com/")
}
            
function gotoUrl1() {
    window.open("https://www.yahoo.com/")
}
            
function gotoUrl2() {
    window.open("https://www.youtube.com/")
}
```

```html
<button class="one" target="_blank" onclick="gotoUrl()"> Google </button>
<button class="two" target="_blank" onclick="gotoUrl1()"> yahoo </button>
<button class="three" target="_blank" onclick="gotoUrl2()"> Youtub </button>
```

The open() method opens a new browser window, or a new tab, depending on your browser settings and the parameter values.

syntax:

```
window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)
```

For More details Click Here: [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There needs to be only one function assigned to all buttons.